# Listview Scrollbar - Vertical Displays but doesn't work, Horizontal Not Displayed but Does work

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime

I have the following ListView defined in a Grid win a `<RowDefinition Height="8">` to take up all the visible area.  The Listview is bound and created and populated on the fly at page creation.  Essentially the list is going to be bigger than the viewable area and taller than the viewable area, so I want to be able to scroll up to down and left to right.

Basically, the vertical scroll bar appears but it doesn't work.  It shows lots of area to be scrolled but it is unmoveable with mouse.  The Horizontal scroll seems to appear off the bottom of the list as the mouse wheel does scroll horizontally, but the scroll bar isn't seen.

```
<ListView
x:Name="itemListViewHorizontal"
AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemListView"
AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
Grid.Row="1"
Visibility="Visible"
Margin="0,-10,0,0"
Padding="10,0,0,60"
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SearchItemsViewSource}}"
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard80PersonTemplate}"
SelectionMode="None"
IsSwipeEnabled="false"
IsItemClickEnabled="True"
ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">

<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
<ListView.GroupStyle>
<GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="7,7,0,0">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="3,-7,10,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ChevronGlyph}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Margin="0,-7,0,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    <GroupStyle.Panel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,80,0"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GroupStyle.Panel>
</GroupStyle>
</ListView.GroupStyle>
</ListView>
```

Essentially, what I want is to have the scrollbars at the left and bottom to scroll side to side or top to bottom.  But no matter what I try, short of getting rid of the ItemsPanelTemplate and ItemsPanel information, which makes a single long list, it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

In changing this, my vertical scrollbar works but horizontal is toast.

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was looking for a much more elegant way of doing this.  Apparently, stackpanel cannot be used for both scrollbars at the same time, though it doesn't explicitly say this.  So, I surrounded my listview with a scrollviewer, using a name and then disabling on snap view.

Problems solved, but I was looking for a way without so much nesting, but, it is what it is.